# how to split text or csv file(100 thousand) into csv files ( each one contains 10k ) based on the lines count?

Tags: shell, unix

how to split  text or csv  file (100 thousand)  into  csv files  (each one contains 10k lines )  based on  the lines count ? Using  *UNIX script*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute this command

```
split -l 10000 big.csv
```

split is part of coreutils package so it is widely available

Comment: this is ok but i need splited files also should be in .csv format

Comment: CSV file splited by line is correct CSV file, maybe just missing header in all but one file. If you want something more, like splitting CSV file into multiple files with header in each, then make it new question. This would be a very different issue.